# Executing parameterized stored procedures using PetaPoco

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, petapoco

It's been two days I'm wrestling with PetaPoco to implement a search solution (evidently with some search parameters) which has custom paging in database. I couldn't figure out how to configure PetaPoco paging with ASP.NET DataPager (which is a whole different question). Anyway I want to use custom paging in database.

I have a stored proc called `GetUsersPaged` like below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUsersPaged] 
@startRowIndex int,
@maximumRows int,
@name nvarchar(300) = NULL,
@email nvarchar(100) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM 
    (
    SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS RowRank
            FROM UserInfo
            WHERE 
        (Nickname LIKE '%'+@name+'%' 
         OR FirstName LIKE '%'+@name+'%' 
         OR LastName LIKE '%'+@name+'%' 
         OR @name IS NULL) 
            AND 
        (Email = @email OR @email IS NULL)

    ) AS UsersPagedList
    WHERE RowRank BETWEEN @startRowIndex AND (@startRowIndex + @maximumRows) 
END
```

and `GetUsersCount` stored proc like below:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUsersCount] 
    @name nvarchar(300) = NULL,
    @email nvarchar(100) = NULL
    AS
    BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM UserInfo
       WHERE 
    (Nickname LIKE '%'+@name+'%' 
     OR FirstName LIKE '%'+@name+'%' 
     OR LastName LIKE '%'+@name+'%' 
     OR @name IS NULL) 
        AND 
    (Email = @email OR @email IS NULL)
   END
```

Now I have two methods for calling these stored procs like below:

```
    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select, false)]
    public List<DAL.UserInfo> GetPagedUserSearchResults(int startRowIndex, int pageSize, string name, string email)
    {
        DBService dbService = new DBService();
        var db = dbService.GetDatabase();
        var list = new List<DAL.UserInfo>();

        if(name != string.Empty && email != string.Empty)
            list = db.Fetch<DAL.UserInfo>(@"EXEC GetUsersPaged @@startRowIndex = @0, @@maximumRows = @1, 
                                            @@name = @2, @@email = @3", startRowIndex, pageSize, name, email);

        else if(name == string.Empty && email != string.Empty)
            list = db.Fetch<DAL.UserInfo>(@"EXEC GetUsersPaged @@startRowIndex = @0, @@maximumRows = @1, 
                                            @@email = @2", startRowIndex, pageSize, email);

        else if(name != string.Empty && email == string.Empty)
            list = db.Fetch<DAL.UserInfo>(@"EXEC GetUsersPaged @@startRowIndex = @0, @@maximumRows = @1, 
                                            @@name = @2", startRowIndex, pageSize, name);

        else if(name == string.Empty && email == string.Empty)
            list = db.Fetch<DAL.UserInfo>(@"EXEC GetUsersPaged @@startRowIndex = @0, @@maximumRows = @1"
                                            ,startRowIndex, pageSize); 
        return list;
    }

    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select, false)]
    public int GetPagedUserSearchResultsCount(string name, string email)
    {
        DBService dbService = new DBService();
        var db = dbService.GetDatabase();
        IEnumerable<DAL.UserInfo> count = null;

        if (name != string.Empty && email != string.Empty)
            count = db.Query<DAL.UserInfo>("EXEC GetUsersCount @@name = @0, @@email = @1", name, email);

        else if (name == string.Empty && email != string.Empty)
            count = db.Query<DAL.UserInfo>("EXEC GetUsersCount @@email = @0", email);

        else if(name != string.Empty && email == string.Empty)
            count = db.Query<DAL.UserInfo>("EXEC GetUsersCount @@name = @0", name);

        else if (name == string.Empty && email == string.Empty)
            count = db.Query<DAL.UserInfo>("EXEC GetUsersCount");

        return count.Count<DAL.UserInfo>();
    }
```

My question is: everything is fine when I'm executing and testing stored procs in db (inside SQL Management Studio). All results respect to paging parameters. But when I call the same stored procs using PetaPoco, it fetches the whole thing and paging is ignored.

For example when I test stored procs in SQL Management Studio with

```
@startRowIndex = 0
@maximumRows = 1
```

and I don't send anything for `@name` and `@email`, it returns just one row which is totally correct. But the same things with PetaPoco, it returns 3 rows in the list. Any idea what's the problem?

Comment: Have you checked using the SqlProfiler what actually gets executed against the database?

Comment: Actually not. But I think, this could be a bug in PetaPoco

Comment: Maybe try : db.Fetch<DAL.UserInfo>(";EXEC GetUsersPaged @@startRowIndex = @0, @@maximumRows = @1, @@name = @2", startRowIndex, pageSize, name); or try : db.Fetch<DAL.UserInfo>(";EXEC @0, @1, @2", startRowIndex, pageSize, name); - I don't see why the second would work over the first.. but in an attempt to get it working (if it still isn't) it's worth trying everything.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting EnableAutoSelect = false?  When I left this on the default setting, the call returned all records.